# Multiple Asynchronous SqlClient Operations - Looking for a good example

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, asynchronous, sqlclient

I have been using Asynchronous operations in my WinForms client since the beginning, but only for some operations.  When the `ExecuteReader` or the `ExecuteNonQuery` completes, the callback delegate fires and everything works just fine.

I've basically got two issues:

1) What is the best structure for dealing with this in a real-life system?  All the examples I have seen are toy examples where the form handles the operation completion and then opening a datareader on the `EndExecuteReader`.  Of course, this means that the form is more tightly coupled to the database than you would normally like.  And, of course, the form can always easily call `.Invoke` on itself.  I've set up all my async objects to inherit from a `AsyncCtrlBlock<T>` class and have the form and all the callback delegates provided to the constructor of the async objects in my DAL.

2) I am going to re-visit a portion of the program that currently is not async.  It makes two calls in series.  When the first is complete, part of the model can be populated.  When the second is complete, the remaining part of the model can be completed - but only if the first part is already done.  What is the best way to structure this?  It would be great if the first read can be done and the processing due to the first read be underway while the second is launched, but I don't want the processing of the second read to be started until I know that the processing of the first read's data has been completed.

Comment: "It would be great if the first read can be done and the processing due to the first read be underway while the second is launched, but I don't want the processing of the second read to be started until I know that the processing of the first read's data has been completed." ----- Do you mean the first and second should begin execution simultaneously, but you dont want the second completed before first completes?

Comment: I connot begin processing the second's completion event until the first completion event's processing has been completed.  i.e. The first query gets a set of nodes and the second query gets a set of lines.  I cannot put the lines in between the nodes until the nodes are instantiated, then I can join them up with the results of the line relationships query.

Comment: You explanation sound that CTE, Common Table Expressions (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) could gives you results in one step. Inside of WITH you define the first query and direct after WITH you use the node of the first query in the second one in the JOIN statement. Is it not so?

Comment: @Oleg The two sets could be combined as one with a join, but it's slower and requires more client processing.  The point is that in general if a process requires multiple independent result sets, but there is some dependency in processing, how do you structure the parallel processing and what is a good example of asynchronous processing which doesn't simply have the forms processing the completion event?

Answer (score 0):

regarding 2)

make the first phase of your model populating asynchronous. 
you will have something like that

```
FisrtCall();
AsyncResult arPh1 = BeginPhaseOne(); //use results from first call
SecondCall();
EndPhaseOne(arPh1); //wait until phase one is finished
PhaseTwo(); //proceed to phase two
```

Comment: To get the bounty, I'm going to want to see a real example code, or a link to an article with a real example which 1) doesn't process the events in a form and 2) shows how to queue two requests but only process the second after the first request has completed and has been processed (and the first request results be processed even while the second is still pending)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on .Net 4, this would be an ideal application of TPL! You could factor your code into tasks like this:

```
TaskScheduler uiScheduler = GetUISheduller();
SqlCommand command1 = CreateCommand1();

Task<SqlDataReader> query1 = Task<SqlDataReader>.Factory.FromAsync(command1.BeginExecuteReader, command1.EndExecuteReader, null);
query1.ContinueWith(t => PopulateGrid1(t.Result), uiScheduler);

SqlCommand command2 = CreateCommand2();
query1.ContinueWith(t => Task<SqlDataReader>.Factory.FromAsync(command2.BeginExecuteReader, command2.EndExecuteReader, null)
      .ContinueWith(t => PopulateGrid2(t.Result), uiScheduler);
```